# Business logic structure in mongoose and restify

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, restify

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to organize my business logic in mongoose. I'm pretty new to MongoDB and still trying to figure out everything.

So, I'm trying to achieve what socialite from Laravel does, I need to login with Facebook, check if the user is already registered, if it is, just login, if it's not, then register with the info from facebook.

I created a `providerAccount` and a `user` model. The `providerAccount` is the schema with the Facebook ID and userId relation, the user is the user's schema with all the fields I need.

I tried to create a `createOrGetUser()` static in the user's schema, which should do exactly what I said earlier, the problem is I just don't know how to properly write this function nor if this is the correct place to write it.

Should I `require()` the `providerAccount` inside my `user` model and keep chaining the queries and `if`s or there is a better way to do this kind of logic?

Thanks!